# Generating all subsets of a given set

Tags: java, collections, combinatorics

I am learning Java Collections Framework. Can someone look at this code for *generating all subsets of a given set* and tell me any issues with it.

```
import java.util.*;
public class AllSubsets {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> original = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); i > 0; i--) {
            original.add(i);
        }   
        System.out.println(generateAllSubsets(original));
    }

    public static HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> generateAllSubsets(Set<Integer> original) {

        HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> allSubsets = new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>();

        allSubsets.add(new HashSet<Integer>()); //Add empty set.

        Iterator it = original.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Integer element = (Integer) it.next();

            //Deep copy all subsets to temporary power set.
            HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> tempClone = new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>();
            for (HashSet<Integer> subset : allSubsets) {
                tempClone.add((HashSet<Integer>)subset.clone());
            }       

            //All element to all subsets of the temporary power set.
            Iterator it2 = tempClone.iterator();
            while(it2.hasNext()) {
                Set<Integer> s = (HashSet<Integer>) it2.next();
                s.add(element);
            }   

            //Merge both power sets.
            allSubsets.addAll(tempClone);
        }   
        return allSubsets;
    }
}
```

Comment: you use vague algorithm, so no one wish to decrypt and and thus you received no answer. To represent a subset, usually an integer in binary representation is used: 0 in a given position means element is absent, 1 - present. To generate all subsets, start with 0 and add 1, counting all integers up to 2^N-1. If you have less than 64 elements, you can use `long` integer, other wise use BitSet, and implement operation of adding 1.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, how can an implementation in an actual language be a "vague algorithm"? Pseudocode can be vague, but this isn't.

Comment: [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#powerSet(java.util.Set)) has same kind of method and check also in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670862/obtaining-powerset-of-a-set-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first, obvious, issue is that generating the set in memory uses a lot of memory. However, making a lazy version is a bit more advanced, so don't worry about it for now.

#### 1. Code to the interface, not the implementation

```
public static HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> generateAllSubsets(Set<Integer> original) {
```

is bad.

```
public static Set<Set<Integer>> generateAllSubsets(Set<Integer> original) {
```

is better.

#### 2. Generics reduce repetition

```
public static <T> Set<Set<T>> generateAllSubsets(Set<T> original) {
```

is better still, because you can use it to find power sets of any set.

#### 3. Generics remove the necessity to do most casts

```
    Iterator it = original.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Integer element = (Integer) it.next();
```

and

```
        Iterator it2 = tempClone.iterator();
        while(it2.hasNext()) {
            Set<Integer> s = (HashSet<Integer>) it2.next();
```

have wholly unnecessary explicit casts (which in the second case generates a warning) because you're using the raw type `Iterator`. Both can also be simplified using the same `foreach` syntax which you use when making the copy of the power set so far.

#### 4. KISS

You have three loops (including the one hidden behind `allSubsets.addAll`), which seems to me to be unnecessarily complicated. If you make a shallow copy first then you can combine the deep copy with the adding an element.

```
public static <T> Set<Set<T>> generateAllSubsets(Set<T> original) {
    Set<Set<T>> allSubsets = new HashSet<Set<T>>();

    allSubsets.add(new HashSet<T>()); //Add empty set.

    for (T element : original) {
        // Copy subsets so we can iterate over them without ConcurrentModificationException
        Set<Set<T>> tempClone = new HashSet<Set<T>>(allSubsets);

        // All element to all subsets of the current power set.
        for (Set<T> subset : tempClone) {
            Set<T> extended = new HashSet<T>(subset);
            extended.add(element);
            allSubsets.add(extended);
        }
    }

    return allSubsets;
}
```

You'll note that I'm using the copy-constructor rather than `clone()`. That's a matter of taste: fundamentally there's no real difference, because they're both special-cased.